# How to name drives according to their position in a multi-bay enclosure?

Tags: linux, zfs, udev

It is important to know a position of a bad drive in a multi-bay device, however default naming of drives e.g `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` etc. does not provide a clue where a particular drive is residing physically.

I have an 8-bay external JBOD enclosure used for backup. It hosts a ZFS pool and is connected to an Arch Linux box. Is it possible on a Linux system which uses `systemd`/`udev` to name drives according to their physical location in the enclosure instead of `/dev/sd*`?

I would like the names to reflect the *physical position of a drive in the enclosure* `/dev/encl1`, `/dev/encl2`... or similar. I would prefer these labels to appear by default instead of `/dev/sd*` in `lsblk` and `zpool status`.

I do know location of every drive in the enclosure, and keep this
information in a file, but it would be way better to see it with
`lsblk` and other commands directly.

I tried to create rules at `/etc/udev/rules.d` like

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block" KERNEL=="sd*" ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="ZR5CTR4V" SYMLINK+="encl1"
```

And I do get such symlinks after running `udevadm trigger`, but they are not equivalent to `/dev/sd*` and I was not able to use them as a substitution.

Comment: There are *already* names that are more informative than `/dev/sd*`. Take a look at `/dev/disk/by-id/` and the other directories under `/dev/disk`.

Comment: @larsks, my specific usecase it to know the position of a drive in the enclosure by its name, so I can find it quickly in case of trouble.

Comment: How about the `by-path`?

Comment: @vidarlo, `by-path` still does not allow to tell that this particular drive is for example located 2nd from the top in the enclosure

Comment: Can you use `lshw -c disk -c storage | grep -E 'bus info|logical name` to give you a hint on the disk bays? I expect that the bus info will be incrementing uniformly following the bay numbers.

Comment: @doneal24, very cool command, I did not know about it! Actually, in my case, I do know positions of each drive, and I just keep this information in a file, but it is much less convenient than directly seeing this information by running `lsblk` for example. I edited question to clarify this.

Answer (score 5):

Writing up my comment as an answer.

Use the command

```
lshw -c disk -c storage | grep -E 'bus info|logical name’
```

to map device names to pci devices. The device id’s will increment uniformly, with the lowest id for bay 1.

You can also use `udevadm` to get the device id in `devices`.

```
udevadm info --name=/dev/nvme6
```

You can now give the disk devices names corresponding to the physical slot they are installed in. Edit or create `/etc/udev/rules.d/my.rules`. You can rename the device with the rules.

```
KERNEL=="nvme*", SUBSYSTEM=="nvme", ENV{PHYSDEVPATH}=="*pci0000:20/0000:20:01.3/0000:25:00.0*", NAME="bay6"
KERNEL=="nvme*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", SUBSYSTEM=="nvme", ENV{PHYSDEVPATH}=="*pci0000:20/0000:20:01.3/0000:25:00.0*", NAME="bay6p%n"
```

If you have sd devices instead or nvme, change the `SUBSYSTEM` to `block`.

It's possible to put in an alias instead of renaming the device. Look at `SYMLINK+="bay6"` in the udev documentation.

Comment: in my case it is already known where drives are located in the enclosure, the question is how to show this information conveniently in the name of the drives. For example `multipath` does it well by creating an `alias` to `wwid` data, and this alias appears as the default name for a drive

Comment: @dimus Added device renaming to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for expansion of your answer @doneal24, as you can see in my question, I did succeed in making aliases, how can I make them show by default though?

Comment: @dimus I don't use zfs so this is a guess. Look at [this](https://plantroon.com/changing-disk-identifiers-in-zpool/) and the man page for zpool-import. It looks like you can use something like `zpool-import -d /dev/bay1 -d /dev/bay2 -d... poolname`.

Comment: yes, i did post an answer about doing just that, but it is only a partial answer, I would love to be able to change default names for drives to have a more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer to the question which does work to provide a bay position information for ZFS:

1. I used `parted` to change labels for ZFS paritions to something like `encl1-3DS` where the first part is the bay position and the second is the unique part of the drive's serial.

```
(parted) p
Model: xxx (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name       Flags
 1      1049kB  4001GB  4001GB               encl4-28P
 9      4001GB  4001GB  8389kB
```

2. `zpool export <zpool-name>`
3. `zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-partlabel <zpool-name>`
4. Now `zpool status -v` shows

```bash
❯ zpool status -v
  pool: ext
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 05:42:24 with 0 errors on Fri Jan  6 20:15:57 2023
config:

    NAME           STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    ext            ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0     ONLINE       0     0     0
        encl1-PT8  ONLINE       0     0     0
        encl7-C32  ONLINE       0     0     0
        encl4-28P  ONLINE       0     0     0
        encl2-N75  ONLINE       0     0     0
        encl5-ZT1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        encl6-9RP  ONLINE       0     0     0
        encl8-88F  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Not sorted, but it is already much better than `/dev/sd*`

Still, I would love to have a more general solution that would make a custom alias a default.